# XNA XACT Where do I place the .xap file?

Tags: xna, xact

I've been trying and looking on the internet for ages now, but where exactly do you place the .xap file? I've read that you should place the file in your content folder, but I have a content folder located in;

TheGame\TheGameContent\

But I also have;

TheGame\TheGame\bin\x86\Debug\Content

Which is it? If I add the .xap file to the latter it recognises it when I refresh the solution explorer, but the former does not.

However, if I add the .xap to the latter it gives an error saying it can't find it when I use the following line of code to access it;

ae = new AudioEngine(@"Content\game_content\audio\xact\Win\xna xact file.xgs");

This line apparently gets the \x86\debug path.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio, go to the Solution Explorer and right click the Content solution (i.e. "TheGameContent (Content)") or a folder in that section and select Add > Existing Item... and select the .xap file. If it isn't in there, it will copy the file into TheGame/Content, but it will also make it ready to load and work within your project.

Basically it's the same as adding an image file to an XNA project, and it will save you all that trouble you are having.